# how to add options menu to listview in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying an option menu in a class that extends ListAcitivity. How do I add an option menu to this activity, so when I click on the option button an options menu appears at the bottom of the screen.

I searched online but most tutorials refer to this function onCreateOptionsMenu() which is part of Activity class and it does not seem to work in the subclass of ListActivity.

Comment: It should work though, can you show some code?

Comment: My apologies. I am new to java and android, I tried the code again (It is really the 50th time) and it worked on my phone. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Java. `ListActivity` (and anything that extends it) inherits all of the features and functions of `Activity`.

Therefore, just overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` will work the same.

Boilerplate code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_xml_name, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_id:
        // action
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

:)

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact code that I was using. I stated in the last comment that I am actually new to android and java. Just in case someone else run into this issue, I uninstalled the app from my phone then installed it through Eclipse and I think this what made it work.

Comment: Yeah. I found that if I manually install an apk to my phone I have to use the phone's interface to uninstall it before it will let me install it later, but the emulator always automatically uninstalls when I do the same thing. So perhaps you were just not getting the most up-to-date version of your apk on the phone. It's good you figured it out though.